# Struggling with Linux IPTables with dynamic IP

Tags: linux, bash, unix, iptables

I built a server that talks to an API; however, the endpoint doesn't have a static ip.  I've been able to successfully create a bash file that will query the ip, write it to a log, then change the iptables on the fly.  Since this is writing to disk, I don't want to do that.

What works: this code will write an entry to the iptables list.

What doesn't work: It keeps doing it every time I run it.  I'm wanting to remove the entry if it's already in.

**Here is the code without a log file:**

```
#!/bin/bash

IPT="/sbin/iptables"

HOSTNAME=google.com

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "This script must be run as root"
        exit 1
fi

new_ip=$(host $HOSTNAME | head -n1 | cut -f4 -d ' ')
old_ip=$($IPT -L -n --line-number | grep $HOSTNAME | head -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -f5 -d ' ')

if [ "$new_ip" = "$old_ip" ] ; then
        echo "first if statment"
        #echo IP address has not changed
else
        echo "first else"
        if [ -n "$old_ip" ] ; then
                echo "second if statement"
                $IPT -D OUTPUT -d $old_ip -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
                $IPT -D INPUT -s $old_ip -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        fi
        echo "generic if"
        $IPT -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d $new_ip --dport 443  -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        $IPT -I INPUT  -p tcp -s $new_ip --sport 443  -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
        #echo iptables have been updated
fi
```

**Here is the code with a log file (Don't want to use):**

```
#!/bin/bash

IPT="/sbin/iptables"

HOSTNAME=google.com
LOGFILE=/home/runrun/testing.log
Current_IP=$(host $HOSTNAME | head -n1 | cut -f4 -d ' ')

if [ ! -f $LOGFILE ]; then
        echo "first if statement"
        $IPT -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d $Current_IP --dport 443  -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        $IPT -I INPUT  -p tcp -s $Current_IP --sport 443  -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
        echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
else
        echo "first else statement"
fi


Old_IP=$(cat $LOGFILE)
if [ "$Current_IP" = "$Old_IP" ] ; then
        echo "second if statement"
        #echo IP address has not changed
else
        echo "second else statement"
        $IPT -D OUTPUT -d $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        $IPT -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        $IPT -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d $Current_IP --dport 443  -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        $IPT -I INPUT  -p tcp -s $Current_IP --sport 443  -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
        echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
        echo iptables have been updated
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem in your script without a log is specifying the `-n` option when filling the `old_ip` variable. `-n` specifies a **numeric** hostname (e.g. the IP). Since you attempt a command substitution with:

```
old_ip=$($IPT -L -n --line-number | grep $HOSTNAME ...
```

`grep $HOSTNAME` will never match because the iptables output does not include hostnames, just IPs. If you don't specify `-n`, and force name resolution, the `iptables` command will likely take minutes to resolve every host and netblock. The man page explains that is best avoided (for good reason)

Frankly, keeping a persistent file (even a temporary file) holding the last IP you are interesting in (or a file with pairs of hostname IPs you can use for the purpose of deleting old IPs from iptables) is probably the most efficient way to go.

(don't forget to look at how/if your distribution provides a persistent iptable config file used to preserve your config across reboots, and if it does, update the persistent copy with the changes after you delete an old IP)

Comment: When I run the script, it always adds an entry to the iptables.  I removed the `-n` and it still is adding an entry to the iptables.  It's never removing anything.  Here is the output when running the script


`
user@computer:~ $ sudo ./nologfile_dns.sh
first else
generic if
`

Comment: If you look at the output from `iptables -vL` you won't get `host.domain.tld`, but you are more likely to get `12-2348-some-net-blk-host.domain.tld` string for each hostname. While it would still contain/match, e.g. `google.com`, the result it would provide would not match a `host.domain.tld` in your `iptables` listing. (if you also time it, it takes a considerable amount of time, especially if you are blocking ranges of addressing in a net-block, etc..) Why are you adverse to a persistent file containing last IP-hostname information?

Comment: When this system boots up, it has a default iptables setup. It blocks everything and only allows ssh to it.  The system does need to reach out to a server online via its dns name.  That ip address changes.  Is there not a way to write an infinite loop with this?

Comment: Generally, the file read at startup is like `iptables.rules` that contains entries like: `-A INPUT -s 54.38.81.231/32 -j DROP`. Most distros provide a way to write a new `iptables.rules` file (or similar) when changes are made so the next reboot will load the last configuration. If I were doing it, for the host (or hosts) that might change IP, I'd keep a short file with `host.domain.tld 111.222.333.444` pairs. Then a short loop over the pairs grabbing the IP and a loop with `iptables -vL > /tmp/iptablestmp` then loop over the IP pairs with `grep -q $theIP || ## handle new address for $theIP`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  It does not use a log file; everything stored in memory.  You can run this as a crontab job too

Requirements: iptables, dig, and an iptables rule that matches the comment "Google"

Here is a sample rule to add:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 7.7.7.7 --dport 443 -m comment --comment "Google" -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Here is a crontab job to run it every 5 minutes.  Put in the PATH var:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
*/5 * * * * /root/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will check the ip address and if it changed, it updates it.  I've looked online for this and hadn't found a solution, but here it is.

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=google.com

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root"
   exit 1
fi

new_ip=$(dig +short $HOSTNAME | head -n2)
old_ip=$(/usr/sbin/iptables --line-number -nL OUTPUT | grep Google | cut -f26 -d ' ')


if [ "$new_ip" = "$old_ip" ] ; then
    echo "IP address has not changed"
else
    echo "IP address has been changed"
    echo "Updating IPTables now"
    DELETERULE=$(/usr/sbin/iptables --line-number -nL OUTPUT | grep Google | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sort -nr)
    for rules in $DELETERULE
    do
        /usr/sbin/iptables -D OUTPUT "$rules"
    done
    for ip in $new_ip
    do
        /usr/sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d "$ip" --dport 443 -m comment --comment "Google" -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    done
fi
```